Network error trying to save screen capture to Local Drive or Google Drive on Chromebook
I'm trying to save a partial screen capture to my Chromebook.
I tried saving it multiple times to either the Local Downloads folder or the Google Drive folder but kept getting a network error.
I don't understand why the network would be involved when saving to the Local Downloads folder.
Is it because the software that does the save to disk is not stored locally on the Chromebook but must be downloaded from the cloud? (The capture itself succeeds. It is the "save as" that raises the error.)
P.S. I am using the built-in screen-capture utility that is accessible on the Chromebook "shelf".  Holding open the possibility that it is a web app of some kind; otherwise, I don't know why there's a network error when I try to save locally.

Is the capture an image or video?

Is the  initial capture being saved? According to Google, "Recordings and screenshots get saved to your “Downloads“ folder" And you can  change that location using Shift + Ctrl + Show windows then select Settings  at the bottom and then the folder. See Chromebook Support
